# Windows phone 8 supports background process (no UI)?

Tags: windows-phone-8

As the title says, now Windows phone 8 supports background process (no UI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there's a two process model available for certain application types, like VoIP.

Comment: If I use both VoIP and background audio, how many processes are there ?

Comment: 3, except you can't really do that, as the VoIP process will take over the audio channel.